# How to split array into chunks of given size? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to work out how I can get such senario to work:

```
MEAL DEAL: $4.99 - Total 3 items
Must includ 1 of each "DRINK, SANCKS, SANDWICH"
```

I have this array:

```
[
  { "CAT": "DRINKS", "QTY": 1, "PRICE": 1.2 },
  { "CAT": "DRINKS", "QTY": 1, "PRICE": 1.5 },
  { "CAT": "SANCKS", "QTY": 1, "PRICE": 2.5 },
  { "CAT": "SANCKS", "QTY": 1, "PRICE": 3.5 },
  { "CAT": "SANCKS", "QTY": 1, "PRICE": 1.5 },
  { "CAT": "SANDWICH", "QTY": 1, "PRICE": 5.3 },
  { "CAT": "SANDWICH", "QTY": 1, "PRICE": 3.0 }
]
```

Based on array above, I need to split it into **chunks of 3 elements** to create a meal deal.

**Looking at array above (7 elements) we can only have 2x Meal deals with 1 item "SNACK" that can't be part of the meal deal just yet because its missing other 2 necessary elements.**

I have tried the forEach loop but it only works for initial meal deal and than rest it dont work out.

```
var PER_CATEGORY_SET ={}
var ITM = "";
MY_ARRAY.forEach(function (my_item){
    var xx = MY_ARRAY.length;

    while (xx > 0) {
        if(ITM !=  my_item.CAT ){
           ITM = my_item.CAT;
           PER_CATEGORY_SET.push({'CAT':my_item.CAT,'QTY':my_item.QTY,'PRICE':my_item.PRICE});
           MY_ARRAY.splice(0, 1);
        }
        xx--;
    }
});
console.log(PER_CATEGORY_SET);
```

Any help would be very much appreciated, I have tried searching for examples to help me work out how I can do it myself (I'm not looking for a copy & paste code)

Comment: What does the question have to do with JQuery?

Comment: @FlatAssembler Sorry, I added it by accident, I have removed it - Sorry

Comment: Split the single array into three arrays, based on the category.  Then perform an algorithm to derive all the combinations of the three arrays.  Once you have that, filter those that match your desired price.

Comment: @Taplar thank you, would it be possible for you to show me an example please?

Comment: Showing you an example would be writing a complete solution.  I would rather you make an attempt first.

Comment: @Taplar I can work of the rest based on your comment but it's this "Split the single array into three arrays, based on the category. " which I cant seem to work out. The ForEach loop i tried was to get that to work but it only works for 1st chunk than it cant work out rest

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5gcpj8hL/  A forEach example of the splitting.

Comment: @Taplar thank you - your example works great when the 'snack, drinks, sandwich' array is pre-defined. However, IF the names differ such as 'burger, cold drink, fries' than we have to manually pre-define then names for array. It's not created dynamically.

Comment: If you cannot rely on the categories being set as a predetermined set of values, then this question is too broad.  Without knowing the confines of your data, there's not a clear cut way to determine how to group things.

Comment: @Taplar I really appreciate your time! thank you very much. I'll try other solutions in which i can make your suggestion work - Hope I can get more input from you in the solutions :D

Answer (score 0):

You could group the objects, based on `cat` and get a cartesian product of it.

```js
var data = [{ CAT: "DRINKS", QTY: 1, PRICE: 1.2 }, { CAT: "DRINKS", QTY: 1, PRICE: 1.5 }, { CAT: "SANCKS", QTY: 1, PRICE: 2.5 }, { CAT: "SANCKS", QTY: 1, PRICE: 3.5 }, { CAT: "SANCKS", QTY: 1, PRICE: 1.5 }, { CAT: "SANDWICH", QTY: 1, PRICE: 5.3 }, { CAT: "SANDWICH", QTY: 1, PRICE: 3 }],
    result = Object
        .values(data.reduce((r, o) => ((r[o.CAT] = r[o.CAT] || []).push(o), r), {}))
        .reduce((a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => [].concat(v, w))), []));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you but can you tell me where does it say it has to be "3" chunks?

Comment: @RVX, do you want to get three items? please add the wanted result to the question.

Comment: I have added it into information about question "I need it in chunks of 3 elements"  so programatically it can be defined how many elements should each chunk have

Answer (score 0):

You could group each object based on the `CAT` value. Get which of the groups have the smallest number of items. Create a meals of that length and take items from each index of the each group

```js
const input=[{CAT:"DRINKS",QTY:1,PRICE:1.2},{CAT:"DRINKS",QTY:1,PRICE:1.5},{CAT:"SANCKS",QTY:1,PRICE:2.5},{CAT:"SANCKS",QTY:1,PRICE:3.5},{CAT:"SANCKS",QTY:1,PRICE:1.5},{CAT:"SANDWICH",QTY:1,PRICE:5.3},{CAT:"SANDWICH",QTY:1,PRICE:3}];

const group = input.reduce((acc, o) => {
  acc[o.CAT] = acc[o.CAT] || [];
  acc[o.CAT].push(o);
  return acc;
}, {})

const groupedArrays = Object.values(group),
      possibleMeals = Math.min(...groupedArrays.map(a => a.length)),
      meals = Array.from({ length: possibleMeals },
                          (_, i) => groupedArrays.map(g => g[i]))

console.log(meals)
```